# Function is undefined in console log?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a tool to convert temperature values from Celsius, Fahrenheit, or Kelvin but the console says the function getTemperature() is undefined?

```
function getTemperature() {
    var fahrenheit = document.formBox.tempF.value;
    var celsius = document.formBox.tempC.value;
    var kelvin = document.formBox.tempK.value;
    var select = document.formBox.select.value;

    //User gives initial temperature in fahrenheit, convert to C and K
    if (select === "GivenF") {
        var c = (5/9)*(fahrenheit-32);
        var k = ((((fahrenheit-32)*5)/9) + 273.15);
        document.getElementById("celsius").innerHTML = "This equals " + c " degrees celsius.";
        document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML = "This equals " + k " kelvin.";
        document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = "";
    }
    //User gives initial temperature in celsius, convert to F and K
    else if (select === "GivenC") {
        var f = ((9/5)*celsius)+32;
        var k = celsius+273.15;
        document.getElementById("celsius").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML = "This equals " + k " kelvin.";
        document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = "This equals " + f " fahrenheit.";
    }
    //Use gives initial temperature in kelvin, convert to F and C
    else if (select === "GivenK") {
        var f = (9/5)*(kelvin-273)+32;
        var c = kelvin-273.15;
        document.getElementById("celsius").innerHTML = "This equals " + c " degrees celsius.";
        document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = "This equals " + f " fahrenheit.";
    };
}
```

Comment: you have made a silly mistake of string concatenation within variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are syntax errors like

```
 ... = "This equals " + c " degrees celsius.";
```

where you miss `+` sign after variable.

It may be something with the way you call the function also, but syntax erros are in the first place.

Comment: Yes; a syntax error in a function definition makes the function undefined.